# Load a PAGE based on a URL variable in jqueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have got a page **gameList.html** that list all the games in a list view.The list items have got a link to the page **gameDetails.html** and Im a passing a URL variable **gametype** to the page.The page **gameDetails.html** has got three pages with IDs simple,advanced and medium.I trying to load the appropriate page based on the value of the URL variable.How do I achieve this?

```
<li><a href="../WebApp/gameDetails.html?gametype=Simple" data-ajax="false">
<li><a href="../WebApp/gameDetails.html?gametype=Advanced" data-ajax="false">
<li><a href="../WebApp/gameDetails.html?gametype=Medium" data-ajax="false">
```

This is what I have got in **gameDetails.html** inside the body

```
<div id="pageSimple" data-role="page"> 

  <div data-role="header">
     <h1>Simple/h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">            

  </div>        

  <div data-role="footer> 
  </div> 

</div>

<div id="pageAdvanced" data-role="page"> 

  <div data-role="header">
     <h1>Advanced/h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">            

  </div>        

  <div data-role="footer> 
  </div> 

</div>

<div id="pageMedium" data-role="page"> 

  <div data-role="header">
     <h1>Medium/h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">            

  </div>        

  <div data-role="footer> 
  </div> 

</div>
```

I have got it sort of working.But im facing another problem now.The correct page is being loaded but its when I hit the back button while im on the Advanced and Medium page it takes me to the Simple page.Is it possible to take me back to **gameList.html**?

The js I wrote in **gameDetails.html**

//NM.Utils.getUrlVars() is what I use to get the value of the URL variable

```
$(function(){   
$.mobile.changePage("#page"+NM.Utils.getUrlVars()["gametype"], {transition:'pop'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any JavaScript to accomplish this, you just need to add [`rel="external"`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) to your links.

For example

```
<li><a href="../WebApp/gameDetails.html?gametype=Simple" rel="external">
```